# Undefined reference when using extern on a c++ object, but not integral type

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm getting undefined reference errors when trying to use extern on a c++ object. It doesn't appear to happen with integral types. What am I missing?! This code below replicates the problem:

file1.cpp:

```
#include <string>

const std::string s("test");
int i = 99;

int main()
{
        extern void Test();
        Test();
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

extern const std::string s;
extern int i;

void Test()
{
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

if i comment out the usage of the 's' std::string variable, the linking errors go away.

There are other questions on SO similar to this, but they all seem to be related to people not defining the variable, which I am!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `const` on `std::string`, it gives `s` internal linkage. Quote from [3.5 Program and linkage]:3:

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.6) has internal linkage if it is
>   the name of
>
> — a variable that is **explicitly declared const** or constexpr and
>   neither explicitly declared extern nor previously declared to have
>   external linkage; or

Answer (score 2):

If you remove const, it works in vc++, and if you define them both extern const, it also works.

```
// file1.cpp
extern const std::string s("test");
extern const int i = 99;

// file2.cpp
extern const std::string s;
extern const int i;
```

If you remove any 'extern' from file1.cpp, it can't compile. If the variables are defined const, you can remove 'extern' from file1.cpp.